# Webstorm Karma test debugging - breakpoint not hit

Tags: debugging, webstorm

I have installed the chrome jet brains extension

I have tests like this:

```
describe('Service tests', function () {


 beforeEach(module('app'));

    it('should have a Service', inject(function($injector) {
        var exist = $injector.has('dataService');
```

etc

but no luck getting breakpoints to hit any where in the tests. I can get the debugger to break when writing debugger, but an unable to step through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have karma-coverage set up in your karma config? It uses instrumented code, so debugging is not possible. Related tickets: http://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/630, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8443

Comment: the only workaround is to have serapate configs for coverage and debugging, with coverage disabled in the latter

Answer (score 2):

If you are building with Webpack you might need to specify the `devtools` option in your `webpack` config property in `karma.conf.js` like this:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
    config.set({
         webpack: {
             ...,
             devtool: 'inline-source-map'
         }
    })
};
```

This solution works for me with Webpack v3.

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you are using Angular and you have removed all the coverage related stuff from your `karma.config` file and are still unable to hit the breakpoints, look into the `angular.json`. It might be having the `codeCoverage` bit set to `true`.

```
"test": {
  ...
  "options": {
    ...
    "codeCoverage": false,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```